# Link that allows web visitors to call admin

Tags: php, javascript, phone-call

A client has requested a feature on his contact-us page where browsers can call only his phone and he will be charged by some online calling service. Does anyone have any thoughts if this is possible?

Comment: Why not simply showing the phone number? I think most people prefer their own telephone to a call out of a browser at the PC.

Comment: Call his phone *using what*? Obviously you can't make a link that when clicked causes my mobile phone to call your landline.

Comment: @Yogu the client wants the visitors to be able to call for free

Comment: @Jon call his phone using an online calling service like skype

Comment: I dont see why you guys downvoted this, the question is seems useful... Unfortunetly I cannot ask anymore questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twilio](http://twilio.com) offers a voip api that spesifically does what you need: [Click to Call](http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/click-to-call)

Note: I am not affiliated with twilio on any level. Request of Original Poster's client would reqiure a third party api/software for sure and will be limited to the features provided with it anyhow.

Comment: How do you know that Twillo support the country of that client?

Comment: Twilio has support for nearly all countries around the world. check the documentation: http://www.twilio.com/pricing/international-calling-rates

Comment: A simple "I don't know." would have made it as well ;)

Comment: Actually i have used twilio for a very similar purpose and it did the job for me. Your obvious effort to turn this into a computer science discussion is nonsense.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of call services which will call both parties - one of those might suit. A google for "Click to call" should find someone in the relevant country.

Answer (score 1):

If your customers have skype, you could post a link to that skype user:

```
<a href="skype:the_skype_name">Call the admin on skype</a>
```

Otherwise, you could use a flash or html5 app.

Answer (score 0):

If skype is an option for both the client and visitor, the simple solution is
`<a href="callto://YourSkypeName">Call us</a>`
If not, use one of services, corresponding to your country, as told Andiih.